# Would (parts of) this question be on-topic at security.se?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-question, scope, specific-question

Over on Computer Science SE, we have a question about implementing an electronic signature system (signature in the sense of the scribble you put at the end of the letter): [How can I implement a secure download page/area on a website which requires a digital signature?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/51574/9550)  That's off-topic on CS.SE but we're not sure what to do with it.

The goal is (my paraphrase) to get a signed copy of the Ts&Cs from a user before allowing them access to the download section of a website. The question proposes a design for a system, and asks if it's OK and how to implement it. Obviously, the implementation part is off-topic, here on IT Security; would the design part be on-topic here? I'm not sure if it's "security enough". If not, do you have any suggestions about where it should go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is about turning high-level security requirements into a concrete workflow. That's a pretty typical type of question for Security.SE.

Although the study of security protocols is on-topic on CS.SE, this question is very firmly on the engineering side (designing a specific system according to concrete constraints), and thus off-topic there.

I have migrated the question.